# Hadoop: NullPointerException when redirecting to job history server

Tags: hadoop, nullpointerexception

I have a Hadoop cluster (HDP 2.1). Everything has been working for a long time, but suddenly jobs have started to return the following recurrent error:

```
16/10/13 16:21:11 INFO Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
16/10/13 16:21:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
16/10/13 16:21:12 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://dev-fiwr-bignode-12.hi.inet:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
16/10/13 16:21:13 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at dev-fiwr-bignode-12.hi.inet/10.95.76.79:8050
16/10/13 16:21:13 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
16/10/13 16:21:13 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
16/10/13 16:21:13 INFO Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
16/10/13 16:21:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1476366871137_0003
16/10/13 16:21:14 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1476366871137_0003
16/10/13 16:21:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://dev-fiwr-bignode-12.hi.inet:8088/proxy/application_1476366871137_0003/
16/10/13 16:21:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1476366871137_0003
16/10/13 16:21:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1476366871137_0003 running in uber mode : false
16/10/13 16:21:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/10/13 16:21:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
16/10/13 16:21:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/10/13 16:21:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%\
6/10/13 16:21:29 INFO mapred.ClientServiceDelegate: Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
16/10/13 16:21:29 INFO mapred.ClientServiceDelegate: Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
16/10/13 16:21:29 INFO mapred.ClientServiceDelegate: Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
Exception in thread \"main\" java.io.IOException:
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.lang.NullPointerException): java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryClientService$HSClientProtocolHandler.getTaskAttemptCompletionEvents(HistoryClientService.java:277)
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.impl.pb.service.MRClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.getTaskAttemptCompletionEvents(MRClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:173)
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.MRClientProtocol$MRClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(MRClientProtocol.java:283)
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:334)
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getTaskCompletionEvents(ClientServiceDelegate.java:386)
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getTaskCompletionEvents(YARNRunner.java:539)
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$5.run(Job.java:668)
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$5.run(Job.java:665)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getTaskCompletionEvents(Job.java:665)
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.monitorAndPrintJob(Job.java:1366)
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1306)
dijkstra.adjacencylist.AdjacencyListDriver.jobRun(AdjacencyListDriver.java:53)
dijkstra.adjacencylist.AdjacencyListDriver.run(AdjacencyListDriver.java:31)
org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
dijkstra.launch.LaunchClass.launchAdjMatrix(LaunchClass.java:226)
dijkstra.launch.LaunchClass.main(LaunchClass.java:199)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by:
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.lang.NullPointerException):
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryClientService$HSClientProtocolHandler.getTaskAttemptCompletionEvents(HistoryClientService.java:277)
...
```

Googling a bit, I've seen these issues:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5703
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5547

They seem to be related. Nevertheless, why was the cluster running properly until now? Nothing was changed in the configuration, the clsuter is not in safe mode, the HDFS space usage is around 0.03%... Any clues? And in the case this is related to the issues above mentioned, any workaround?

Many thanks, I'll stay tuned for your answers or additional info requirements.

Comment: Just confirm one thing, does it write anything in the output file after job execution?
Usually, distributed systems have network and hardware failure issues which are inevitable. Now, I am also curious to know what's the actual issue.

Comment: @Azim, the job seems to internally run many other several jobs... I don't like such an idea, anyway I'm not the develper of the job but the admin of the cluster. Being said that, the user tells me the first bunch of, let's say, sub-jobs finish and write in HDFS. The problem is with the second bunch of jobs: nothing is written in HDFS because the History Server rises NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues is similar to 5703, judging by the stack trace, and as stated in that bug:

"The method GetTaskAttemptCompletionEventsResponse() fetched a Job by calling verifyAndGetJob(), but it never checked if job was null or not, which was the root cause of this issue."

There is a job lookup using a job id, the job is not found.

In that bug it lists a scenario in which a job history server (JHS) is queried about a finished job but JHS failed to receive the info for that job.

There seems to be open issues regarding job termination and job history uploads that allow this exception to happen when job history upload fails.  In the bug the issue was triggered by restarting the node writing the history before the history upload is complete, or by that node having no good nodes to write the history to.

Unfortunately, there is nothing else here that might help identify what caused the history upload to fail in your case, but that appears to be the underlying source of the issue.  Your job history server has no record of the job that successfully completed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please, check the comment I've added to my original post, for further information.